# Flask: Communication between JS and Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a system where people can add roles and remove roles from a list (This is what it looks like: https://s7.gifyu.com/images/idea9b50431c2edc0295.gif ) but want a way to save that data when the user clicks "Save". I was thinking I could use JS to get the contents of the ul and run a python function to save the data, but I can figure out how to do it. I've tried [Passing data from javascript into Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537254/passing-data-from-javascript-into-flask) and [Python Flask calling functions using buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899484/python-flask-calling-functions-using-buttons) but couldn't get it working. The problem with the second one is that I couldn't pass data into the function.

This is the code for the ul:

```html
<ul class="role_box_roles" id="rbroles">
    {% for role in modroles %}
    <li class="role_box_role" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <button class="role_remove_button" onclick="remove_option('{{role}}', this)" type="button" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">-</button>
        <span>{{role}}</span>
                        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    <li id="plusbutton"><button class="role_add" type="button" onclick="show_options()">+</button></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to save the role names ({{role}}).

The save button is below the ul

`<div id="save_changes_button" class="save_changes_button" onclick="">Save</div>`

I'm trying to save it in a dict stored in the flask file (the python file that is running flask/the website)

I can give extra information if it's required.

Comment: Where is the `save` button? What information do you want to save? Where do you wants to save it?

Comment: @SeyiDaniel I've added that information to the the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Save Button
> Create Ids for tags ( and )

```
<span id="myspan">{{role}}</span>
<a id="save_changes_button" class="save_changes_button">Save</a>
```

> JS
> Listen for click on `save_changes_button`, once this happens

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#save_changes_button').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#save_changes_button').prop("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
         data : { my_role : $('#myspan').text() }, //grab text between span tags
         type : 'POST',
         url : '/saverole', //post grabbed text to flask endpoint for saving role
         success: function (data) { console.log('Sent Successfully') },
         error: function (e) { console.log('Submission failed...') }
    });
});
})
</script>
```

> FLASK

```
@app.route('/saverole', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def saverole():
    s_role = request.form['my_role'] #parse received content to varaible
    role_dict = {'role': s_role} #construct a dictionary with variable 
    return ('', 205) #or whatever you wish to return
```

Comment: Feel free to ask for explanation

Comment: Yeah, an explanation would be nice. I've never seen this before and would quite like to know how it works. @SeyiDaniel

Comment: I've added some comments to help you understand

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The only thing is, I don't get the desired result. Instead I get a `127.0.0.1 - - [20/Aug/2020 17:59:51] "POST /saverole HTTP/1.1" 405 -`

Comment: This is a picture of the message: https://s7.gifyu.com/images/error-message.png

Comment: I've updated the flask endpoint to accommodate 'post' and 'get' methods.

Comment: Now I get this message https://s7.gifyu.com/images/error-message3d37c85762a8e2a4.png

Comment: Please work with the last code update. There was a variable in my initial code name `subscriber_email`, I have since changed it to `my_role`. But it appears you haven't done that.

Answer (score -1):

the only way to send data from a webpage js back to your server is via a ajax POST/GET method from your js

by defining a route which accepts the data in flask and a js ajax call to POST that data to that flask route onClick (or any other user changes on webpage, handled by js)